# Is this what a bad fit means?

Tags: postdocs, motivation

I'm 5 months into my 1st data science postdoc and I already feel overwhelmed, intellectually isolated, and now unmotivated. Is this what a bad lab fit means? Let me elaborate below.

I just completed my Phd in CS. The project was heavy on method development with application in Biology. For my postdoc, I wanted to continue this but in a different biology field.

My current lab arrangement is strange. All my team mates are biologists, 1 PI is a MD, the other is data scientist. I've been given lots of small projects to work on while I familiarise myself with the field. Now I'm given yet another dataset, but was told to come up with the biology questions to answer myself. I feel very much out of depth and place but was told I need to *show some leadership* as I am a postdoc, not an RA. I'm beginning to suspect I'm in the wrong lab, but since I'm new, I also wonder whether this is what a postdoc is all about and that I should stop moaning.

Intellectually isolated. Apart from my data science PI who is also very biology focused, I found myself not able to banter with anyone else about data science/CS ideas or findings. It's like the enthusiasm is no longer there as they're all only interested in biology. Very often, I end up falling back to my PhD team and bantering ideas with them, constantly looking back at the good old days of trading just pure mad ideas or discussing about new discoveries.

Is this a bad fit? Or am I just moaning and being very unfair about the lab? I suspect it's the first and that I need to move on ASAP, but I am not sure to be honest.

Comment: I suspect only you can answer. But perhaps one thing to reflect on is whether your bosses are trying to fit a square peg (you) into a round hole. It's possible that they are -- but it's also possible that they are perfectly happy for you to be a square, and they are looking for you to do square research and even set up collaborations with other squares.

Comment: Always a pertinent question: Have you talked to your advisers about the issue?

Comment: I have, and I was told to show some leadership and come up with the questions since I'm a postdoc not an RA. I was also told that the lab has no infrastructure and resources to support computational method development, and that method development is not data science. This made me very confused. I no longer understand what data science is.

Comment: @cag51 it is possible. If that's the case, I'm at a huge disadvantage as I'm inexperienced, operating on a new field, and surrounded by circles not squares. Shouldn't this be better suited for a group leader position rather than a postdoc fresh from phd??

Comment: (Not an answer neither an advice): If I were you (and I was), I would continue my work and search at the same time for another position that suits me better (whatever "suits me" means). I would keep a good relationship with the current supervisor.

Comment: Yes, it sounds like a bad fit. They were looking for a biologist with some CS creds, and got a computer scientist with interests in biology applications. Both sides are probably unhappy. Not sure what else is there to say about this.

Comment: @xLeitix Seems like that should be an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think your boss expects you to use new data to generate testable hypotheses. After all, data science is a tool. That said, I am a bit puzzled as to why you chose this academic lab instead of industrial postdoc in any of the three public cloud companies. But I think your motivation for coming to this lab is that you want to use data science to contribute to biological science.

I can’t tell you if this is a bad fit as you described, but I think the questions for you to consider are: are you able to use data to create hypotheses? Does the data indicate things or evidence that doesn’t fit conventional wisdom? What experiment (ie, knock out genes, ligand binding site mutation) can you propose to validate your hypotheses? Can you build a classifier or tree from data to categorize these observations? And does the tree recapitulate or defy known  biological principles? These may yield valuable research topics (speaking bluntly, grant proposal). I think these are what your boss is expecting you do deliver.

Comment: _I am a bit puzzled as to why you chose this academic lab instead of industrial postdoc in any of the three public cloud companies_ - Sorry, where is this coming from?

Comment: Academia labs are not the only place to do peer reviewed research. For those who thinks academia is not their gig, there are industry options.

Comment: _For those who thinks academia is not their gig, there are industry options_ - Sure, but I didn't see anything in their post suggesting the OP thinks academia is not for them, and especially not suggesting that they felt this way when they were applying for jobs.

Answer (score 1):

The situation you are describing looks to me like a somewhat clumsy attempt at trying to do multi-/inter-disciplinary research. While your situation is "whole lab working in X while I have background in Y", and the one I have experience with is "a couple of people in X, Y and Z each", the effects seem quite similar -- team/lab members feel intellectually isolated and miss "scientific banter" while questioning whether this environment is helpful for developing their research profile in the direction they want to take it.

The take-away for me is that running interdisciplinary research, projects and teams well is difficult; it's often difficult for people from different fields to communicate efficiently, the projects identified in the cross between the two often seem like "toy problems" to both sides, and it is very difficult for somebody with background in X to pose a hypothesis in Y.

That said, a good postdoc should include a component that is outside of your immediate comfort zone. The skills obtained during your PhD should allow you to get to grips with a different research area. It is an opportunity to widen your horizons and diversify your profile. The perfect ratio of familiar to completely new will vary from person to person, and you need to figure out what yours looks like.

To see whether this is a bad fit, I think you should re-examine your priorities, pros and cons of staying v leaving, and then make the decision accordingly:

1. **Staying**

   As mentioned, real interdisciplinary research is hard. However it can have far-reaching consequences in one or multiple research fields. If you want to have a interdisciplinary profile, obtaining results from such a project is a very big step in the right direction.

   On the other hand, I believe the key to doing this successfully is communication and collaboration. A researcher with a background in X can not be expected to produce a research question in Y. In fact, the hypothesis to look at should come from *both* X and Y.

   If you go down this route, I would suggest trying to establish a new dialogue with your current advisors. You are the authority on CS/DS (that's why they hired you); with very little background in biology. You need to come up with research questions *jointly* with your advisors, who have a biology background, and a *joint* plan for dissemination -- you probably want to consider journals they've never heard of, and the other way around too. Pulling off a successful interdisciplinary project must surely count as a *show of leadership*.
2. **Leaving**

   If your goal is to find a place to do good interdisciplinary research, well, that's not easy. A number of positions will feel intellectually isolating, and actually feel like "X engineer with applications to Y" rather than "research in X", similar to your current position. The other side of the medal is real research in X, applied to Y, led by somebody from X, which sadly doesn't seem directly relevant to Y to most Y researchers.

   It is likely that all interdisciplinary project will likely present a similar challenge to a varying degree (or exactly the opposite problem). Additionally, if you're looking specifically for a marriage between fields X and Y, your options are much more limited than a recent PhD in "just" X.

   Finally, it is worth considering whether you actually *want* to do interdisciplinary research in applications of X to Y. Which aspect of it attracts you the most? If it's just that improving Y has e.g. a direct and beneficial social impact, consider applying X to any field of high social importance. If it is that Y just provided interesting challenges, consider continuing doing research in X, unbounded. But if it is Y specifically, you might need to get background knowledge in an area different to your current background even if it means stepping far out of your comfort zone.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it looks like they wanted someone to do their data science for them and are expecting you to make yourself useful. That is, to solve biology problems with data science: what else is data science for if not for solving problems in various fields?

You, on the other hand, seem to want to discuss the data science itself, compare approaches, examine properties of data... And it seems that you would not find it in this lab indeed.

I would say I have not seen this arrangement anywhere except for CS/ML labs which act as a workshop for an entire department or even university, and they often deal with a huge range of problems, sometimes from social sciences to geology. Industry has more specialized ML-focused groups, but in natural sciences within academia, ML is not yet seen as something warranting dedicating an entire subfield or a lab to. In part it is because the interpretable AI is still rather weak, and without it, data science usage is limited to methodological aspects. To put it bluntly, it is "just" advanced statistics, and you do not need a dedicated Lab of Pearson Type VI Distributions in Plant Biology: instead, you have a Plant Biology lab which brings their statistical problems to statisticians.

If you want to do data science with applications in X, two main options exist: you either join a lab specializing in X as a specialist in data science and largely handle data science problems solo (which is the situation you are in right now; I am in a similar arrangement, but content with it) or you join a data science lab and pester labs in field X for collaboration. The latter option seems to fit your profile better.

Comment: Eh, I'd push back a bit against the "in natural sciences within academia, ML is not yet seen as something warranting dedicating an entire subfield or a lab to" bits; there is a lot of heterogeneity in how biologists view the utility of ML and AI, and also "not yet seen as" sounds like in some future you're imagining every biology lab is going to have a sub-lab to do AI. I think that's rather silly; biologists use tools from all sorts of disciplines, and they need people familiar with using those tools, but that doesn't mean it makes any sense at all to also have people developing new tools.

Comment: The people working on new tools are naturally going to be in groups that work on new tools. Typically, if a biology lab has need for a particular new tool, they're going to work in *collaboration with* some other lab that has expertise in that tool, whether that tool is a piece of analytical equipment (collaborating with physicists, chemists, engineers, etc) or data analysis (statisticians, computer scientists, bioinformaticians, etc).

Comment: @BryanKrause Thank you for your comment; I seemingly have failed to make it clear. Yes, I am much with you on "the people working on new tools are naturally going to be in groups that work on new tools". The caveat here is that it is not always the case, and I've seen quite a few labs with homebrew solutions for something someone else knows how to do better. As for the "in some future you're imagining..." - I do think that it is possible that in some, not all, areas there will be labs heavily specializing on these tools in some subfield of biology. I'd argue some genomics labs are almost that.

Comment: But yes, a TL;DR would be "if you are interested in tools way more than biology, you need a tools lab, not a biology lab".

Comment: Sure, certainly; there is an entire field of bioinformatics that lies on the intersection of computer science, statistics, and biology, but that's a fairly narrow slice of biology in general and even in bioinformatics most groups are using existing tools rather than making their own, just like field biologists tend to buy binoculars and notebooks rather than making their own optics and paper.

Comment: Thank you for the insight folks. I must admit, I came to the lab with the view of solving biological problems with data science. However, I did not expect to be told to go hunting those biological problems myself, which is what biology focus groups are in general. I came from a CS lab with collaboration with biology lab. The latter came up with a problem, we came up with the solution to solve the problem, and I think that's where I want to end up.

Comment: @BryanKrause the field exists but is only appreciated in some parts of the world. I think labs operating in that area are very concentrated in some part of Western Europe and US, with some scattered in much smaller scale elsewhere. These labs tend to be headed by a statistician or CS guru who have interest in solving biology problems rather than say facial recognition or database management (both are classic CS stuff).

Comment: All of these conversation reminds me of what the MD PI said "I hire people for their expertise. As you can see, each lab member around you is an expert in a field or sub-field". We are a diverse group composed of a person who is either an immunologist, a wet-lab tech expert (idk what to call this person), a gene regulatory network expert, a gene mutation expert, all within a biology group trying to study a disease. I guess, these guys are all an expert in a biology field, while I'm more of a ML/data expert in CS field.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen people who have been "scientific outsiders" in their labs or work environments in the sense that their interest and expertise was in some way only loosely related to what the others do. Sometimes this kind of thing is required because a lab may need this kind of expertise occasionally, but most if not all people there can't really relate to it.

Now you can say that this is a "bad fit" and look for something else, but I have seen people who have managed to "cultivate" such a position in some often creative ways. This usually involves contacts to people working elsewhere (surely at least to avoid intellectual isolation) who may be closer to what you want to do. Chances are as a postdoc of whom personal initiative is expected, you can well work on collaborative projects with people who do not belong to the lab. This may comprise people who develop ML methods, or people who provide you with biological problems that you can contribute to. Obviously the first candidates would be those you already know from past experiences, but you may get into contact with other people doing stuff of which you have an idea what you could contribute.

I also wonder whether you could just interpret the "show some leadership" demand as a license to do what you're good at. Would it be a problem if you focus more on methodological work, as long as you can make an at least weak case that there are biological problems where this can be applied? Maybe you need to look around a bit for such problems, and maybe with some creativity you can connect this to the data set that you are apparently expected to do something about.

One thing that I recommend strongly is to collect some information about what "counts" for your lab, like publications in specific journals, grants etc. In many places you have a lot of freedom if you just produce something that counts. You could maybe spend 80% of your time on projects that you have chosen more or less freely for yourself as long as you contribute to the lab's output in a way that serves the lab. (Chances are it won't be like that everywhere, you've got to find it out.)